# Wordpress Create Category AJAX Response

Tags: ajax, wordpress, categories

I currently have a plugin that allows a user to activate/deactivate categories to drive a menu.  I've created an option for the toggle and have it functioning in the create form and edit form seamlessly.  The only place I can't seem to add it is to the AJAX return from wordpress when the category is created.  I can create the column when the Categories page is loaded but don't know how to tap into the AJAX Return without modifying the core.  Is there a hook that I'm unaware of that allows you to modify this return?

Answer (score 2):

Using Akmal's answer, this is my script to check if the Taxonomy-Category was created or not.
Thanks Akmal.

Wordpress version 3.8.2

```
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
            var queryStringArr = settings.data.split('&');
                if( $.inArray('action=add-tag', queryStringArr) !== -1){
                    var xml = xhr.responseXML;
                    $response = $(xml).find('term_id').text();
                    if($response!=""){
                        console.log('This is the action.');

                    }
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you try to run some Javascript after ajax return (after add new category)?

Try to put below code in your code when you create the custom field in category form  :

```
       $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {

         var queryStringArr = settings.data.split('&');

         if ($.inArray('action=add-tag', queryStringArr) !== -1){
             your_javascript_function(); //this is your js function
         }

       });
```

Comment: Error: settings.data.split is not a function?