# Display top level Woocommerce product tag with taxonomy images

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Looking to display images(thumbnails) added to the `product_tag` taxonomy

I was able to successfully add the image upload field to the `product_tag` taxonomy in the backend by altering the following to work with tags:

https://pluginrepublic.com/adding-an-image-upload-field-to-categories/

```html
<?php

/**
 * ADD THUMNAIL IMAGE TO PRODUCT TAGS
 **/


/**
 * Plugin class
 **/
if ( ! class_exists( 'CT_TAX_META' ) ) {

class CT_TAX_META {

  public function __construct() {
    //
  }
 
 /*
  * Initialize the class and start calling our hooks and filters
  * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function init() {
   add_action( 'product_tag_add_form_fields', array ( $this, 'add_product_tag_image' ), 10, 2 );
   add_action( 'created_product_tag', array ( $this, 'save_product_tag_image' ), 10, 2 );
   add_action( 'product_tag_edit_form_fields', array ( $this, 'update_product_tag_image' ), 10, 2 );
   add_action( 'edited_product_tag', array ( $this, 'updated_product_tag_image' ), 10, 2 );
   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'load_media' ) );
   add_action( 'admin_footer', array ( $this, 'add_script' ) );
 }

public function load_media() {
 wp_enqueue_media();
}
 
 /*
  * Add a form field in the new product_tag page
  * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function add_product_tag_image ( $taxonomy ) { ?>
   <div class="form-field term-group">
     <label for="product_tag-image-id"><?php _e('Image', 'hero-theme'); ?></label>
     <input type="hidden" id="product_tag-image-id" name="product_tag-image-id" class="custom_media_url" value="">
     <div id="product_tag-image-wrapper"></div>
     <p>
       <input type="button" class="button button-secondary ct_tax_media_button" id="ct_tax_media_button" name="ct_tax_media_button" value="<?php _e( 'Add Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?>" />
       <input type="button" class="button button-secondary ct_tax_media_remove" id="ct_tax_media_remove" name="ct_tax_media_remove" value="<?php _e( 'Remove Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?>" />
    </p>
   </div>
 <?php
 }
 
 /*
  * Save the form field
  * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function save_product_tag_image ( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
   if( isset( $_POST['product_tag-image-id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['product_tag-image-id'] ){
     $image = $_POST['product_tag-image-id'];
     add_term_meta( $term_id, 'product_tag-image-id', $image, true );
   }
 }
 
 /*
  * Edit the form field
  * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function update_product_tag_image ( $term, $taxonomy ) { ?>
   <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
     <th scope="row">
       <label for="product_tag-image-id"><?php _e( 'Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?></label>
     </th>
     <td>
       <?php $image_id = get_term_meta ( $term -> term_id, 'product_tag-image-id', true ); ?>
       <input type="hidden" id="product_tag-image-id" name="product_tag-image-id" value="<?php echo $image_id; ?>">
       <div id="product_tag-image-wrapper">
         <?php if ( $image_id ) { ?>
           <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image ( $image_id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
         <?php } ?>
       </div>
       <p>
         <input type="button" class="button button-secondary ct_tax_media_button" id="ct_tax_media_button" name="ct_tax_media_button" value="<?php _e( 'Add Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?>" />
         <input type="button" class="button button-secondary ct_tax_media_remove" id="ct_tax_media_remove" name="ct_tax_media_remove" value="<?php _e( 'Remove Image', 'hero-theme' ); ?>" />
       </p>
     </td>
   </tr>
 <?php
 }

/*
 * Update the form field value
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function updated_product_tag_image ( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
   if( isset( $_POST['product_tag-image-id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['product_tag-image-id'] ){
     $image = $_POST['product_tag-image-id'];
     update_term_meta ( $term_id, 'product_tag-image-id', $image );
   } else {
     update_term_meta ( $term_id, 'product_tag-image-id', '' );
   }
 }

/*
 * Add script
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
 public function add_script() { ?>
   <script>
     jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
       function ct_media_upload(button_class) {
         var _custom_media = true,
         _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
         $('body').on('click', button_class, function(e) {
           var button_id = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
           var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
           var button = $(button_id);
           _custom_media = true;
           wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
             if ( _custom_media ) {
               $('#product_tag-image-id').val(attachment.id);
               $('#product_tag-image-wrapper').html('<img class="custom_media_image" src="" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-height:100px;float:none;" />');
               $('#product_tag-image-wrapper .custom_media_image').attr('src',attachment.url).css('display','block');
             } else {
               return _orig_send_attachment.apply( button_id, [props, attachment] );
             }
            }
         wp.media.editor.open(button);
         return false;
       });
     }
     ct_media_upload('.ct_tax_media_button.button'); 
     $('body').on('click','.ct_tax_media_remove',function(){
       $('#product_tag-image-id').val('');
       $('#product_tag-image-wrapper').html('<img class="custom_media_image" src="" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-height:100px;float:none;" />');
     });
     // Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281995/wordpress-create-product_tag-ajax-response
     $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
       var queryStringArr = settings.data.split('&');
       if( $.inArray('action=add-tag', queryStringArr) !== -1 ){
         var xml = xhr.responseXML;
         $response = $(xml).find('term_id').text();
         if($response!=""){
           // Clear the thumb image
           $('#product_tag-image-wrapper').html('');
         }
       }
     });
   });
 </script>
 <?php }

  }
 
$CT_TAX_META = new CT_TAX_META();
$CT_TAX_META -> init();
 
}
```

My product tags have been modified to support a hierarchy and I was also able to display only Woocommerce top level `product_tag` with the following (working but with no thumbnails)

```
$taxonomy = 'product_tag'; //Choose the taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy ); //Get all the terms

foreach ($terms as $term) { //Cycle through terms, one at a time

// Check and see if the term is a top-level parent. If so, display it.
$parent = $term->parent;
if ( $parent=='0' ) {

$term_id = $term->term_id; //Define the term ID
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); //Get the link to the archive page for that term
$term_name = $term->name;
 $slug = $term->slug;
 $factwpslug = "/shop/?fwp_category=";
 $distance = "&fwp_sort=distance";


echo '<li><a class="'. $slug . ' top-level-cat-nav" href="' . $factwpslug . $slug . $distance . '"><span class="label">' . $term_name . '</span></a></li>';

} }
```

Now that I have that working I'm looking to show the thumbnails in the frontend that have been uploaded to the each `product_tag` with the id of `product_tag-image-id` as in the snippet. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
   // Get the current category ID, e.g. if we're on a category archive page
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID; 
   // Get the image ID for the category
$image_id = get_term_meta ( $cat_id, 'category-image-id', true );
   // Echo the image
echo wp_get_attachment_image ( $image_id, 'large' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to do two things:

1. Get the image id
2. Output the image.

Here's an updated version of your loop that does those two things. You can change the second parameter of `wp_get_attachment_image()` to change the image size.

```
$taxonomy = 'product_tag'; //Choose the taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy ); //Get all the terms

foreach ($terms as $term) { //Cycle through terms, one at a time

// Check and see if the term is a top-level parent. If so, display it.
$parent = $term->parent;
if ( $parent=='0' ) {

$term_id = $term->term_id; //Define the term ID
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); //Get the link to the archive page for that term
$term_name = $term->name;
$slug = $term->slug;
$factwpslug = "/shop/?fwp_category=";
$distance = "&fwp_sort=distance";

// Get the image ID here using the $term_id from above and the meta key you used to save the ID
$image_id = get_term_meta ( $term_id, 'product_tag-image-id', true );


// Use wp_get_attachment_image() to get the image HTML
echo '<li><a class="'. $slug . ' top-level-cat-nav" href="' . $factwpslug . $slug . $distance . '"><span class="label">' . $term_name . '</span>' . wp_get_attachment_image ( $image_id, 'large' ) . '</a></li>';

}
}
```

Comment: And just like that we have success. Should have asked hours ago but It's always good to keep trying different options. Thank you. This may be useful to others as well.