# Wordpress JS: Get category id after adding in admin page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In Admin Page after successfully adding a category, I want to display a message that the category has been added by JS.

How to get a response with ID in the ajax SUCCESS after adding?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1y57vfd Hope this gives you some clues

Comment: Thanks. I found a function that sends html - wp_ajax_add_tag in ajax-actions.php. The response returns the WP_Ajax_Response class.

Comment: Maybe wp-ajax-response.min.js will give an answer

Comment: Check this maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281995/wordpress-create-category-ajax-response and this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116616/hook-onto-add-new-category

Comment: Thanks. This is it!